# Invalid Base64 string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, base64

I'm sending a base 64 string from Android to a .NET web service written in C#.  I've logged the string and it's coming through just fine:

`MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjFVH+fZ60DB7RZFiTePo9wJfkNu//TfODTJCiHv9cwwrxmiwVzHDXWhjzkgyUGBH08YO8bAMdzu4NALD3dlBux4QkSg2yvJmJjULCbaxSTE82aJDzjUOz7KoutTHFK0INFEiINWo7vdKSLiqiXpzfjCfV6DKRbM6DkKmEdFz1SOCWS+f8zs5gheke/ykI6JokzvD+Tw5n2AhHis7cuWJx8e/5BziPMLHbhsoYrpMzGl3SGqBKBoasxXiCgYfvS5RpI57oidGojvNbqsZBA30cbmX6IjXBs61O3zhgY25HKHp5yjHuMXNoNd4GY6Ya/l6yKPqNcKz1x37CP4NfkckbwIDAQAB`

When I try to decode it like this: `Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedKey)` I get the following error:

`System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.`

OK, so it gives me some possible errors, even though as far as I can tell that's a valid base 64 string.  I decided to find out which error condition it's hitting:

```
catch(FormatException fe)
    {
        m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        "Error verifying purchase: " + fe);

        if(decodedKey != null)
        {
            if(decodedKey.Length % 4 != 0)
            {
                m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        "Incorrect length of base 64 string: " + decodedKey.Length);
            }
            else if(decodedKey.EndsWith("==="))
            {
                m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        "Too many closing padding characters");
            }
            else
            {
                int firstPadding = decodedKey.IndexOf("=");
                string padding = null;
                if (firstPadding > -1)
                {
                    padding = decodedKey.Substring(firstPadding);
                }
                Regex r = new Regex("[^=]*"); // any character but =

                if(padding != null && r.IsMatch(padding))
                {
                    m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        "Illegal padding character " + padding);
                }
                else
                {
                    Regex all = new Regex("[^0-9a-zA-Z\\+/=]"); // Any character but 0-9, a-z, A-Z, +, /, and =
                    if (all.IsMatch(decodedKey))
                    {
                        string matches = "";
                        foreach (Match match in all.Matches(decodedKey))
                        {
                            matches += " " + match.Value;
                        }

                        m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                            "Illegal base 64 character(s):" + matches);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string beforePadding;
                        if (firstPadding == -1)
                        {
                            beforePadding = decodedKey;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            beforePadding = decodedKey.Substring(0, firstPadding);
                        }

                        if (beforePadding.Contains("="))
                        {
                            m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                                "Padding occurs at illegal position " + beforePadding.IndexOf("="));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                                "Unknown base 64 error, possibly .NET is full of crap");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.ERROR, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                            "Decoded key is null");
        }
    }
```

The message I get in my log is `"Unknown base 64 error, possibly .NET is full of crap"`.  So what am I missing?  Is this not a valid base 64 string?

UPDATE:
To make this even simpler, I hard-coded the string in C#:

`byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjFVH+fZ60DB7RZFiTePo9wJfkNu//TfODTJCiHv9cwwrxmiwVzHDXWhjzkgyUGBH08YO8bAMdzu4NALD3dlBux4QkSg2yvJmJjULCbaxSTE82aJDzjUOz7KoutTHFK0INFEiINWo7vdKSLiqiXpzfjCfV6DKRbM6DkKmEdFz1SOCWS+f8zs5gheke/ykI6JokzvD+Tw5n2AhHis7cuWJx8e/5BziPMLHbhsoYrpMzGl3SGqBKBoasxXiCgYfvS5RpI57oidGojvNbqsZBA30cbmX6IjXBs61O3zhgY25HKHp5yjHuMXNoNd4GY6Ya/l6yKPqNcKz1x37CP4NfkckbwIDAQAB");`

Still the same failure.  No idea how this can happen.  I didn't have much success trying to create a minimal example (I only dabble in .NET programming).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be decoding for me. Whats the string supposed to say?

Comment: I've just successfully converted the exact string that you've provided, and it worked fine. My guess is that the string you've shown in the question isn't the exact string you're trying to convert. Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SamMarion It's a cryptographic public key, it doesn't say anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet interesting, did you do that with a C# console application?  I'll work on a minimal example.

Comment: Yup, just a tiny console application. The `Main` method consists of: `string text = "[...]"; var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);`

Comment: My mistake misread your question. I can confirm console app is decoding properly.

Comment: Your string is valid and doesn't throw any errors. Make sure you're trying to convert the same string you included in the question.

Comment: @Youssef13 Thanks, I copied and pasted from my log, so I don't know how to be any more sure.